# Autofac is resolving IEnumerable<IContravariantInterface<ConcreteObject>> as IEnumerable<IContravariantInterface<object>>[0]

Tags: c#, autofac

```
public interface IDomainValidator<in TDomain>{}

public interface IDomainValidation<TDomain> {
    void Validate(TDomain domain);
}

public class DomainValidation<TDomain> : IDomainValidation<TDomain>
{
    public DomainValidation(IEnumerable<IDomainValidator<TDomain>> validators)
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

I'm having an issue where contravariant interfaces are being resolved as an empty array of `IEnumerable<IDomainValidator<object>>`.  My unit/integration tests are working fine so I have to assume there is something else being registered that is causing the problem.

Is there are way for me to determine how these Closed Types are being returned as object instead of the registered types that implement those closed types?

**Update 1**

I realized that I was calling this from a generic type and that it was actually the one that is likely to be having the problem.  `DomainValidation<TDomain>` is also coming across with object which explains the list of domain validators.  DomainValidation is being registered with:

`builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(DomainValidation<>)).As(typeof(IDomainValidation<>));`

It is being injected into a class such as:

```
public class Implementation
{
    public Implementation(IDomainValidation<SomeClass> validation) {...}

}
```

This class is the one that technically is wrong.  It is showing as object as well

**Update 2**

The IComponentRegistration is showing the correct type of `IDomainValidation<SomeClass>`, it does have the ContravariantAdapter and the service shows the correct type.  the Target is showing up as `+     Target  {Activator = DomainValidation`1 (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Flightdocs.Infrastructure.Validation.Domain.IDomainValidation`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope} Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration {Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration}` Which I'm guessing is where the problem is.  Now I'm stuck as to why this is occurring.  I'm assuming something is registering as `IDomainValidation<object>`

Comment: how are you registering the type(s) that implement IDomainValidator with autofac?

Comment: `.AsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IDomainValidator<>)); ` One thing I realized is that it is being inserted into a generic implementation class.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since `IContravariantInterface<T>` is contravariant (e.g. it contains `in` arguments), it means that an `IContravariantInterface<ConcreteObject>` can be casted to `IContravariantInterface<ConcreteSubObject>` but not to `IContravariantInterface<object>`. Casting it to `IContravariantInterface<object>` would allow a consumer to pass in something completely different than `ConcreteObject` (e.g. `System.String`) which would obviously break the class implementing `IContravariantInterface<ConcreteObject>`.

So from this sense it is obvious that a list of registered `IContravariantInterface<ConcreteObject>` would end up as zero instances of `IContravariantInterface<object>`. To be able to do this, you would have to change `IContravariantInterface<T>` to covarant (i.e. using the `out` keyword), but that would disable `T` as input argument.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what my issue was.  I have another module I use (MediatR) that suggested the use of `builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());` It apparently doesn't work so well with Contravariant generic interfaces.  Once I removed it then those interfaces were filled with the correct object type.